# OrientDB OSQL Comments

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

In SQL, I can create a comment using "--" and then everything else for the rest of the line is ignored.

Is there something similar in OSQL?

I've tried using "--" and /* */.  In Studio, they are colorized by the syntax highlighter but if I execute a query such as:

```
/* this is a comment */
SELECT FROM V
```

or

```
-- this is also a comment
SELECT FROM V
```

I'll get an error message...

This is with OrientDB Community 2.2.14

Any advice is appreciated :)

Comment: Hello, there's an issue open about this problem - https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/4651

Comment: Ok... so the TL;DR version is that this is an ongoing issue for many years... the issue you linked is closed but links to [another issue](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5762) that has been open for nearly a year. With the final conclusion that comments are implemented but disabled?  My specific use case is for allowing comments in batch scripts -- having this would be a big help ;)